# Explode function or from other reasons?

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I have a code in php it takes a well formatted string such as 'field,operator,value' and produces a WHERE statment to MySQL  database query.
if the two fields names below end with the same characters such as 'id' like 'id' and 'classid' it produces strange behavior. such as the following test.php file:

```
<?php
$where = $_GET['where'];
$tokens = multiexplode(array("^", "~", "(", ")"), $where);
$where= str_replace("~"," OR ",$where);
$where = str_replace("^", " AND ", $where);
foreach ($tokens as $item) {
    if (!empty($item)) {
        $where = str_replace($item, getOperand($item), $where);
    }
}
echo 'WHERE '.$where;

function multiexplode($delimiters, $string)
{
    $unifydelimters = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $conditions = explode($delimiters[0], $unifydelimters);
    return  $conditions;
}
function getOperand($item)
{
    $extokens = explode (",", $item);
    switch (trim($extokens[1])) {
        case 'eq':
            return trim($extokens[0])  . " = '" . trim($extokens[2]) . "' ";
            break;
        case 'neq':
            return trim($extokens[0])  . " != '" . trim($extokens[2]) . "' ";
            break;
        default:
            return "";
            break;
    }
}
```

If you test it in the browser like this:
http://localhost/test/test.php?where=id,eq,1^classid,eq,1X
Where X is any number from 0 to infnity it will echo the following line:
note that both fields id and classid end with 'id'

```
id = '1' AND classid='1' X
```

But if tested with the following urls it works fine:

1. http://localhost/test/test.php?where=id,eq,1^classid,eq,MX where M>1 and X is any number
2. http://localhost/test/test.php?where=id,eq,1^class,eq,1X , X is any digit
3. http://localhost/test/test.php?where=id,neq,1^classid,eq,1X,, X is any digit

Any idea why this is happenning??

Thanks,

Comment: if it works fine , what should be the expected behaviour ?

Comment: this one: id = '1' AND classid='1' X

Comment: if tested with: http://localhost/test/test.php?where=id,eq,1^classid,eq,19 for example it will show: id = '1' AND classid='1' 9

Comment: instead number , u need X ?

Comment: You can pass arrays as query params which would make this MUCH easier i.e. `localhost/test/test.php?where[id]=1&where[classid]=1`

Comment: When tested with: http://localhost/exagent/test.php?where=[id],eq,1~[classid],eq,19
It will return: WHERE [id] = '1' OR [classid] = '19'
But why:  http://localhost/exagent/test.php?where=id,eq,1~classid,eq,19

gives:  WHERE [id] = '1' OR [classid] = '1' 9   ??